# Native Boot VHD Error Code: 0xc000000e

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I started by creating a VHDX using Hyper-V in an external drive which when I added the VHDX to bcd it boots fine from the external drive but when I wanted to copy the VHDX on my SSD when I attempted to boot I keep getting the message

```
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors

File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
Error Code: 0xc000000e
```

also, note that the VHDX file boot up fine in the Hyper-V

E: is an external drive and
D: it's my SSD which is an internal drive

Here is my boot config for the one in the external drive

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {119a1640-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
device                  vhd=[E:]\VMs\Windows 10 DEV\Virtual Hard Disks\Windows 10 DEV.vhdx,locate=custom:12000002
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows10ProDEV
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                vhd=[E:]\VMs\Windows 10 DEV\Virtual Hard Disks\Windows 10 DEV.vhdx,locate=custom:22000002
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {119a163f-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

and also here is the rest of my boot config

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
flightsigning           Yes
default                 {e58d1c8c-1742-11eb-8fa3-b47a6ba6a9de}
resumeobject            {119a1648-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
displayorder            {e58d1c8c-1742-11eb-8fa3-b47a6ba6a9de}
                        {119a1649-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {e58d1c8c-1742-11eb-8fa3-b47a6ba6a9de}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {e58d1c8d-1742-11eb-8fa3-b47a6ba6a9de}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {e58d1c8b-1742-11eb-8fa3-b47a6ba6a9de}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
vga                     No
quietboot               No
usefirmwarepcisettings  No
bootlog                 No
sos                     No

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {119a1649-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
device                  vhd=[D:]\InsiderDATA\Windows10DEV.vhdx,locate=custom:12000002
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows10ProDEV
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                vhd=[D:]\InsiderDATA\Windows10DEV.vhdx,locate=custom:22000002
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {119a1648-5c79-11eb-b4bf-0492261d09e8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Update:

Just tested and it all works fine on my C: drive not sure why it's not working on that drive

Comment: The VHDX boots from `E:`. Is that the SSD disk? If not, you should redo. See [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu#step-3-detach-the-vhd-copy-it-to-a-new-device-and-attach-it-optional).

Comment: @harrymc the E: drive is the HDD which is a USB3 external drive and D: is an internal SSD
also the clone of the vhdx is in D: at \InsiderDATA\Windows10DEV.vhdx

Comment: You have two of them? I don't know what went wrong, but perhaps you should detach both, reboot, then reattach the one on disk.

Comment: @harrymc so you're saying the one on SSD won't boot at all even though it's on an internal drive?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. I trust it's an exact copy of the one that works, so all I can recommend is to redo the attach carefully.

Comment: @harrymc I redid everything and the VHDX still not booting I made an VHDX from a new ISO even but i also tested C: and that works which its really odd

Comment: How are you attaching it?

Comment: I experience the exact same behavior. Yesterday it worked, today not anymore. When I move the VHDX to C: and adjust via bcdedit accordingly it does boot. I could boot the VHDX from Hyper-V normally before moving it to C:. (Where it came from and C: are physically 2 different M.2 SSD drives, and both not older than a few months).